# how to load components with database data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fill a component with database data - I have an image and some description that is fetched from Google Firestore. At the moment I am struggling because the component is being rendered before the data is fetched and put into the components.

My code is listed below. It is in another file and then is run in the file I want to display the data in. I also know that my data is being fetched from the database correctly because I am printing to the console and when I run the code, the right data is displayed in the console.

Thanks!

```js
function DailyView({itemImage, itemEmotion, itemReason, itemMood, itemTime}) {

    const db = getDatabase();
    const getEmotions = ref(db, 'users/' + global.uid);
    onValue(getEmotions, (snapshot)=>{
        var data = snapshot.val();

        for (const value of Object.values(data)) {
            console.log(value["entry"]["feeling"])
          }

        const numEntries = Object.keys(data).length
        console.log(numEntries)

        console.log(Object.values(data)[0]["entry"]["reason"])
        global.item1Emotion = Object.values(data)[numEntries-1]["entry"]["feeling"]
        global.item1Reason = Object.values(data)[numEntries-1]["entry"]["reason"]
        global.item1Mood = Object.values(data)[numEntries-1]["entry"]["mood"]
        global.item1Time = Object.values(data)[numEntries-1]["entry"]["time"]
        global.item1Time = Moment(global.item1Time).format('D MMM YYYY - h:mma ')
        global.item1Image = getImage(global.item1Emotion)



        

    })



    return (


        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Image style={styles.emotions} source={global.item1Image}/>
                <View style={styles.ViewReasons}>
                    <Text style={styles.emotionText}>{global.item1Emotion}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.emotionSub}>Reason: {global.item1Reason}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.emotionSub}>Mood: {global.item1Mood}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.emotionSub}>{global.item1Time}</Text>
                </View>
        </View>

    );
}
```

Comment: It's an inevitable fact of all AJAX calls. You send the request and it comes "some time" after, well after the component has rendered. You need to use the component's state to change once the request completed, take the render values from there, and in the meantime display somethnig else to show the data is not there yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a boolean state to prevent rerender of component until data is fetched.
Sample code:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

return (
{loading ? (
//Your code
):(
//Custom no data found component or something like that
)}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into React Suspense, it was created exactly to address your issue.

https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html